# MK_ADDON_ENABLE : run callbacks: running callbacks: waiting for app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx pods: timed out waiting for the condition

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I'm trying to enable ingress addon by typing:
`minikube addons enable ingress`
I get this Error:

```
`X Fermeture en raison de MK_ADDON_ENABLE : run callbacks: running callbacks: [waiting for app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx pods: timed out waiting for the condition]`
```

I did try to see kubectl pods and it shows:

```
`NAMESPACE       NAME                                        READY   STATUS              RESTARTS      AGE
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-admission-create-6xqc7        0/1     Completed           0             105m
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-admission-patch-5qxwp         0/1     Completed           1             105m
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller-5959f988fd-wngnn   0/1     ImageInspectError   0             105m
kube-system     coredns-565d847f94-kdcf6                    1/1     Running             1 (23m ago)   107m
kube-system     etcd-minikube                               1/1     Running             1 (23m ago)   107m
kube-system     kube-apiserver-minikube                     1/1     Running             1 (23m ago)   107m
kube-system     kube-controller-manager-minikube            1/1     Running             1 (23m ago)   107m
kube-system     kube-proxy-zzrwv                            1/1     Running             1 (23m ago)   107m
kube-system     kube-scheduler-minikube                     1/1     Running             1 (23m ago)   107m
kube-system     storage-provisioner                         1/1     Running             3 (20m ago)   107m`
```